# Remote Connection Desktop Manager 2.7 does not support dpi scaling anymore?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdc-manager

I upgraded Microsoft **Remote Desktop Connection Manager** from 2.2 to 2.7, but the new version DOES NOT SUPPORT DPI-Scaling anymore!

In version 2.2, you could define a fixed size for the remote server (e.g. 1920x1080), and then you could scale it to any client size you wanted. Therefore, on a 4K monitor, you had always  had a very fine view of your server.

But now, in Version 2.7, I need a microscope to view my servers ;))

What happened? How can it be that a version of 2010 supports 4K monitors BETTER than a version from 2014 ????
Already the "Help->About" dialog is ill-scaled !  ;)

Has anyone a solution, other than going back to 2.2 ?

Answer (score 40):

To clarify where to find this checkbox, go to the actual .exe file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Remote Desktop Connection Manager and right click the .exe file and click the Compatibility tab.[image: O]

2018 Windows 10 Update (1803/1809)

There are new cascading dialogs as shown below
[image: 2018 Compatibility tab]
[image: DPI settings tab]

Comment: Windows 10 _(unsure which version - I have Creators Update)_ makes this a bit more complicated because there are now multiple modes under a checkbox named **Override high DPI scaling behavior**: Scaling performed by Application, System, or System (Enhanced).

Answer (score 9):

RDCMan.exe --> Properties --> uncheck “Disable display scaling on high DPI settings”.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows 10 the dialog is slightly different.

Right click on the executable and choose Properties from the context menu. Swap to the Compatibility tab and clear the checkbox labelled 'Override high DPI scaling behavior.'.

[image]